# How do I use predefined apache ENV variable in .htaccess file within regular expression

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

### Problem:

I have a number of subdomains like foo.website.com, bar.website.com and so on.
One of them is the resources.website.com and the resources from it need to be available for all other ***.website.com subdomains.
Obviously, the browser with foo.website.com (with a .js resource from resources.website.com) is running into CORS problem.

### Working code:

I am trying to configure my .htaccess of the resources.website.com to determine whether the request is performed from ***.website.com and the following solution works perfectly fine

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|ttf|otf|eot|woff|ico)$">
    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(.*\.website\.com)$" AllowOrigin=*
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AllowOrigin}e env=AllowOrigin
</FilesMatch>
```

### What I would like to do:

Id like to be able to keep the .com (the zone) outside of the .htaccess in the apache configuration files. (I have multiple environments under different zones so when the code, including the htaccess files, gets deployed on other zones, it is totally neutral).
In apache configuration files I have

```
SetEnv domain_zone com
```

.. and I would like to use this variable in the code above`s regexp (if its possible) like:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(.*\.website\.%{domain_zone}e)$" AllowOrigin=*
```

.. but I obviously lack .htaccess skills. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using alternative regex format?
m#regexp#